Can statistical tests be applied to analyze temperature anomalies in vaccine refrigerators across different shifts and days?
Background:
I'm analyzing the vaccine refrigerator's internal temperature data collected during COVID pandemic (2021-2022) from all over an country. I measured the internal temperature of the 1077 refrigerators every 30 seconds over a period of 1-2 years through IoT monitoring System.
However, some of the refrigerators have insufficient amount of data due to loss of connection and maintenance. Thus I filtered the refrigerators collected the data over 1 year at least. As a result, 448 vaccine refrigerators are remaining.


Aim of analysis:
My aim is to analyze the frequency of temperature anomalies(under 2°C or over 8°C) and duration of anomalies based on two criteria:


Shift (Day/Evening/Night)
Day of the Week

I hypothesize that there will be differences in the occurrence of temperature anomalies and duration of anomalies in vaccine refrigerators by shift and day of the week.
For each refrigerator, I have calculated the total number of anomalies frequency and the duration of anomalies observed during each shift over 2 years. Here’s a sample of the data:


Data Example:
The data examples below are samples of the data I collected.
1-1) Frequency by shift

1-2) Frequency by day of the week

2-1) Duration by shift
Although these duration data are presented as means, I have the total anomaly data.
Since the total dataset is so large, it's difficult to review it all.
Thus, I present the sample of duratino mean of anomalies.
(hh:mm:ss)

2-2) Duration by day of the week



I want to use this data to check if there are differences in the frequency and duration of temperature anomalies according to work hours and days of the week, using data from vaccine refrigerators measured over two years. 
To do this, I tried to apply various methods such as Wilcoxon signed-rank test, Friedman test, and generalized linear mixed models, but I found it difficult to apply them in the way I wanted. Given that the data is not strictly repeated measures, Wilcoxon signed-rank test, Friedman test and GLMM are not directly applicable.


What would be a good way to test this? Or would it be sufficient to simply show it descriptively using statistical techniques without using hypothesis tests? Or should I try a different approach?
Plus, given the limitations of the original analysis, I explored the possibility of grouping the vaccine refrigerators by region and conducting a one-way ANOVA or Kruskal-Wallis test. Is this a viable approach?
Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I think you should be able to used mixed models for this. Refrigerator ID is a random effect, and day of the week or shift are fixed effects.
One thing to keep in mind is that my summarizing mean duration for each refrigerator, you're losing information. If you set up day and shift as predictors, then you have repeated measurements for each fridge, which is a good situation for using random effects. So you don't need to summarize means and regress means - you can just use the direct data.

Thank you very much for your response. However, I have a question regarding the mixed model you mentioned. In the data example 1-1) Frequency by shift, the number of temperature anomalies calculated according to the shift is simply the total number of anomalies that occurred over the entire measurement period for each refrigerator. Therefore, I think it is difficult to consider this as continuously repeated measurements.
For example, if there is a vaccine refrigerator where one temperature anomaly occurs each day during Day, Evening, and Night, and it was measured for 2 years,

then the data would be represented as 730, 730, 730 (365 days * 2 years) in the table. Can such data be considered repeated measures and used in a mixed model?
If the above approach is incorrect, what would be the correct way to apply the model? I feel like I might be missing something important. I would appreciate your help.

If the data is aggregated to sums within each time period, then it can't be used as repeated measures within each time period, but it can still be grouped by fridge ID as a random variable. If you disaggregate the data, then it could be counted as a repeated measure, and you'd probably want to use Poisson Regression to model counts.

Thank you very much for your response. Since I’m a beginner, I’m not entirely sure if I’ve understood correctly. So, does this mean that it’s not possible to analyze the data from 448 refrigerators all at once using a mixed model, but it is possible to disaggregate and analyze the data for a single refrigerator? For example, if Refrigerator A was monitored for the entire day on March 21, 2021, would it be possible to apply the analysis to the Day, Evening, and Night data for that specific day?

If that’s correct, would I need to analyze the data for all 448 refrigerators individually in order to draw general conclusions about temperature anomalies in vaccine refrigerators?

So you could disaggregate the data, but you don't need to. By using a random effect of fridge ID, you would essentially say that some fridges naturally have more or less anomalies that others. This would help control for the effect of the individual fridge, and leave you to look at overall effects of weekday and shift beyond that.

I see. However, there are still some parts that I find difficult to understand. I apologize for any confusion on my part. So, according to what you’ve explained, does it mean that when the data is aggregated, it is no longer considered repeated measures, making it unsuitable for applying GLMM or similar methods, but it is still possible to check for differences by work shift and day of the week using descriptive statistics? And when the data is not aggregated, it can be treated as repeated measures, making it possible to apply GLMM or similar methods?
